# Python array, write a large array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 100*100 array in python and I used:
`f.open(file_name)` and `f.write(matrix_name)` to write it in this file. Actually the matrix was written in the file but in this format:

```
[[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 8 91 1
   . 
   .
   .]
[  7 8 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 22 3 4  5 6  6
   .
   .
   .]
[  . 
   . 
   .
]]
```

so my problem that each row from the matrix was written in many rows in the file (e.g. row 1 was written in 17 rows in the file), because I need each row in the matrix printed in one row in the file.. so totally I need a 100 row in the file, not more than the 100 rows.

Comment: can you add your code ?

Comment: Are we talking about `numpy` arrays here? The `numpy` library has several options of writing data from an array to a file for you, rather than just dumping the text representation into a file.

Comment: My array (a) has a size 100*100 and I used f = open('dd.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(a)), but when I opened the file, I found that each row (100 elements) is written in more than one row in the text file (formatting problem)... so I need each row in the matrix is shown in one row in the text file..(in other words: I want to make the line size more bigger when I write the matrix in the text)

Comment: Khaled, the fundamental question is whether this is a Numpy array.  It certainly looks like it is, but only you can tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a Numpy array to a text file, you can use [`numpy.savetxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt) or the [`tofile()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html#numpy.ndarray.tofile) of the array.  The specifics depend on the output format you need.  You should also consider using some binary format, which is more efficient to read and write.

Comment: @Khaled If this Answer is what you are looking for: Please consider Accepting it, so other user can see that your problem is solved! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work